# How to center a line of text in a fixed width string?

Tags: shell, text-alignment

I have a standard banner that I use for all of my servers and I've typically entered them by hand, but as my fleet of servers is growing, it's time to automate this.

Typically, my banner should look like this:

```
*****************************************************************
*       .:Welcome to hostname.internal.mynet.net:.              *
*                                                               *
* This is a private server maintained by and exclusively for    *
* use by me. No authorization is given or granted to any party  *
* unless explicit permission is given. Attempts to circumvent,  *
* disable, or otherwise interfere with normal operation will be * 
* prosecuted to the fullest extent of applicable laws.          *
*                                                               *
*              UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS PROHIBITED                   *
*****************************************************************
```

This is the desired effect, but my hostnames are of varying characters, so it sometimes does not format correctly, for example:

```
*****************************************************************
*       .:Welcome to somelongrandomhostname.internal.mynet.net:.     *
*                                                               *
* This is a private server maintained by and exclusively for    *
* use by me. No authorization is given or granted to any party  *
* unless explicit permission is given. Attempts to circumvent,  *
* disable, or otherwise interfere with normal operation will be * 
* prosecuted to the fullest extent of applicable laws.          *
*                                                               *
*              UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS PROHIBITED                   *
*****************************************************************
```

and if a shorter hostname:

```
*****************************************************************
*       .:Welcome to abc.internal.mynet.net:.        *
*                                                               *
* This is a private server maintained by and exclusively for    *
* use by me. No authorization is given or granted to any party  *
* unless explicit permission is given. Attempts to circumvent,  *
* disable, or otherwise interfere with normal operation will be * 
* prosecuted to the fullest extent of applicable laws.          *
*                                                               *
*              UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS PROHIBITED                   *
*****************************************************************
```

The relevant code I use in my script to generate this is:

```
# banner
echo "
*****************************************************************
*       .:Welcome to $hostname.internal.mynet.net:.             *
*                                                               *
* This is a private server maintained by and exclusively for    *
* use by me. No authorization is given or granted to any party  *
* unless explicit permission is given. Attempts to circumvent,  *
* disable, or otherwise interfere with normal operation will be *
* prosecuted to the fullest extent of applicable laws.          *
*                                                               *
*              UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS PROHIBITED                   *
***************************************************************** " > banner
```

I'm not sure how or what to use as the best tool to generate the banner exactly as provided in the first example regardless of the length of the hostname? Looking for ideas, the "frame" (as indicated by the asterisk characters) should be a fixed value.

Comment: You can calculate how much spaces you want starting with `${#hostname}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with the parameters in this snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh

for h in io sun moon earth quaoar neptune ganymede alphaCentauri; do
  pad=$(printf '%*s.:Welcome to %s.internal.mynet.net:.\n' \
       -$(expr 20 - ${#h} / 2) " " "$h")
  printf '* %-75s *\n' "$pad"
done
```

which gives output like

```
*                    .:Welcome to io.internal.mynet.net:.                     *
*                    .:Welcome to sun.internal.mynet.net:.                    *
*                   .:Welcome to moon.internal.mynet.net:.                    *
*                   .:Welcome to earth.internal.mynet.net:.                   *
*                  .:Welcome to quaoar.internal.mynet.net:.                   *
*                  .:Welcome to neptune.internal.mynet.net:.                  *
*                 .:Welcome to ganymede.internal.mynet.net:.                  *
*               .:Welcome to alphaCentauri.internal.mynet.net:.               *
```

Which uses `${#h}` to get the number of characters in `$h`, divides that by two, and uses 20 minus that number of spaces to pad to the left.
Note the use of the `%*s` printf format specifier with a *negative* argument to indicate *left justified* placement. The result is then used for a fixed width 75 character string.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful, and I was able to glean what I needed out of it to make it work.